# Javascript problems when converting a string to an array and then back again

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to solve a Javascript challenge on Codewars.

An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is an isogram. Ignore letter case.

```
isIsogram( "Dermatoglyphics" ) == true
isIsogram( "aba" ) == false
isIsogram( "moOse" ) == false // -- ignore letter case
```

My effort is below:

```
    function isIsogram(str) {
    var arr = str.split("");
    var seen = {};
    var out = [];
    var length = arr.length;
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         var item = arr[i].toLowerCase;
         if(seen[item] !== 1) {
               seen[item] = 1;
               out[j++] = item;
         }
    }
    console.log(out.toString.toLowerCase);
    console.log(str.toLowerCase);
    if (out.toString.toLowercase === str.toLowerCase) {
     return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

In codewars the result of my

```
console.log(out.toString.toLowerCase); is undefined
```

and the result of

```
console.log(str.toLowerCase); is [Function: toLowerCase].
```

This means my solution always evaluates to false.

I would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction or highlight my errors instead of giving me the solution so I can learn more effectively. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString` and `toLowerCase` are functions. In Javascript, to execute a function, you must add parenthesis on to the end of the function name:

```
out.toString().toLowerCase()
//          ^^            ^^
```

You need to do this for all your functions:

```
arr[i].toLowerCase()

str.toLowerCase

out.toString.toLowercase() === str.toLowerCase()
```

*(Note that calling `.toString()` on an array will include commas, e.g. `"a,b,c,d,e"`. Probably doesn't matter for this use case, but just to highlight that)*

Answer (score 2):

This may be a simpler answer.

```js
function isIsogram(str){

  // Turn all letters of the string to lower case and split it into an array. 

  var letters = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  var checkLetters = [];
  
  /* Check to see if the letter appears in the checkLetters array.
     If the letter is not already in the array it will push the letter into it. */

  letters.forEach(function(letter) {
    if(checkLetters.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
      checkLetters.push(letter);
    }
  });

  /* Now we have two arrays. If the letters array has non-duplicate letters then 
     it will be the same length as the checkLetters array. If not, the checkLetters array
     will be shorter. */

  /* Return true or false depending on whether the lengths of both arrays are equal */
    
  return letters.length === checkLetters.length ? true : false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

toString and toLowerCase etc are **functions**

use:

```
out.toString().toLowerCase()
```

however, for out, I think you want to do out.join('').toLowerCase()

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can improve your solution, by doing in the functional way, using **hashmap** system, and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value

So, your code will be more clean.

```
  function isIsogram(str) {
    //Create our hashmap
    var hashmap = {};
    //Return value of 'every' loop
    return str.split("").every(function(elm){
      //If our hashmap get current letter as key
      return hashmap.hasOwnProperty(elm.toLowerCase())
      //Return false, str is not an Isogram
      ? false
      //Otherwise, set letter as key in our hashmap,
      //we can check the next iteration
      : hashmap[elm.toLowerCase()] = true;
    });
  }

console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics'));
console.log(isIsogram('moOse'));
console.log(isIsogram('aba'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've solved this, but just for variety.
By ignoring case sensitivity, first change the input to lowercase.

```
function isIsogram(str) {
     // Change word to lower case
    str = str.toLowerCase();
      // split the word into letters and store as an array
    var arr = str.split("");
      // get the length so the array can be looped through
    var len = arr.length;
      // an array to contain letters that has been visited
    var seen = []
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // check if letter has not been visited by checking for the index
      if(seen.indexOf(arr[i])<0){
         // if the letter doesn't exist,add it to seen and go to next letter
        seen.push(arr[i]);
      }else{
         // if letter exists, the word is not an isogram return false
        return false
      }
    }
       // the loop is complete but each letter appeared once, the word is an isogram
   return true
}

console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics'));
console.log(isIsogram('moOse'));
console.log(isIsogram('aba'));
```